# How to insert multiple data from dynamic table to mysql in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Can someone help me, please?
I try to save a value from multiple dynamic boxes from bootstrap into MySQL?

I have tried much suggestion but only the first row inserted, no other data from the added table.  seem like the loop isn't working.

this is one of my code to insert the data.

my view  :

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="col-md-12 column">
         <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" 
            id="tab_logic">
            <thead>
               <tr >
                  <th class="text-center">
                     Bilangan
                  </th>
                  <th class="text-center">
                     Nama
                  </th>
                  <th class="text-center">
                     Tarikh Lahir
                  </th>
                  <th class="text-center">
                     Tempat Lahir
                  </th>
                  <th class="text-center">
                     Warganegara
                  </th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr id='addr0'>
                  <td>
                     1
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <input type="text" name='nama_siblings[]'  
                        placeholder='Nama' class="form-control"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <input type="text" name='tarikh_lahir_siblings[]' 
                        placeholder='Tarikh Lahir' class="form-control"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <input type="text" name='tempat_lahir_siblings[]' 
                        placeholder='Tempat Lahir' class="form-control"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <input type="text" name='warganegara_siblings[]' 
                        placeholder='Warganegara' class="form-control"/>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr id='addr1'></tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
   <tr>
      <td height="100"></td>
   </tr>
   <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Tambah</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Buang</a>
</div>
```

```
<SCRIPT>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      var i=1;
      $("#add_row").click(function(){
      $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input name='nama_siblings"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Nama' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td><td><input  name='tarikh_lahir_siblings"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Tarikh lahir'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='tempat_lahir_siblings"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Tempat Lahir'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='warganegara_siblings"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Warganegara'  class='form-control input-md'></td>");

      $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
      i++; 
     });
     $("#delete_row").click(function(){
         if(i>1){
         $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
         i--;
         }
     });
});

</script>
```

My controller :

```
$xsscleanibu_id = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('ibu_id')); 
$xsscleannama_siblings = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('nama_siblings'));   
$xsscleantarikh_lahir_siblings = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('tarikh_lahir_siblings'));   
$xsscleantempat_lahir_siblings = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('tempat_lahir_siblings'));   
$xsscleanwarganegara_siblings = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('warganegara_siblings')); 

foreach($rows as $row){

   $nama_siblings = $nama_siblings[$index];
   $ibu_id = $ibu_id[$index];
   $tarikh_lahir_siblings = $tarikh_lahir_siblings[$index];
   $tempat_lahir_siblings = $tempat_lahir_siblings[$index];
   $warganegara_siblings = $warganegara_siblings[$index];

   $data2 = array(
   'ibu_id'=>$xsscleanibu_id,
   'nama_siblings'=>$row,
   'tarikh_lahir_siblings'=>$xsscleantarikh_lahir_siblings,
   'tempat_lahir_siblings'=>$xsscleantempat_lahir_siblings,
   'warganegara_siblings'=>$xsscleanwarganegara_siblings
   );
   $this->inq_model_dev->insertMonday($data2);
}

   if($row)
   { 
      echo "<script>alert('Data Berjaya disimpan');
window.location = '".base_url('index.php/efast/dashboard_efast')."';</script>";
    }
    else 
    { 
      echo "<script>alert-danger('Data gagal disimpan');window.location = '".base_url('index.php/efast/pendaftaran')."';</script>";
    }
```

My Model :

```
function insertMonday($data2){

     foreach($data as $data2){
        $this->db->insert('data_anak', $data2);
     }
}
```

Comment: Are you 100% Certain that your Model code is what you are actually using?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw yes, after many copy and paste, i really mess up. can u help me with this

Comment: You haven't defined `[$index]` in the foreach loop.

Use `foreach($rows as $key => $row)` and then use `$key` inplace of `$index`

Comment: still cannot insert into table

Answer (score 0):

When you insert multiple data use **insert_batch** codeigniter default function.

```
 function insertMonday($data2){

        foreach($data as $data2){
            $this->db->insert_batch('data_anak', $data2);
        }

    }
```

Comment: still the data did not insert into table